# Correct use of AND,OR operator with grails criteria

Tags: grails, criteria

I am trying to build a criteria using grails `createCriteria`.criteria like this

```
Controller.createCriteria().listDistinct(){
and {
   or{
          or{
             //condition1
             //condition2
            }
          or{
             //condition3
             //condition4
            }

     }

//condition 5
}

}
```

but what I get is this:

```
 where
        (
            (
                (
                    condition 1
                    or condition2
                ) 
                or (
                    condition 3 
                    or condition 4
                )
            )
        )
```

How should I correctly position the clauses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried using only one OR to simplify things.
I'm thinking in something like:

```
and {
    or{
        //condition1
        //condition2
        //condition3
        //condition4
    }
    //condition 5
}
```

It will generate less complicated SQL